# Save Embedded images and files from outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I want to save embedded images from outlook. After my analysis i found that user can embed images, and also PDF files etc. But in case of embedding PDF or other than image files(In outlook by using Insert menu and then Object option) the mail item attachment object also contains a .mso file(An MSO file is sent with email attachments and contains information that allows the attachment to be rendered within the email message) which i am not sure like i need to save it or not.

1)So is there any need to save or process the mso file or can i just ignore it and save all other file types?

2)Based on my observation even if user embed pdf file it will be attached as image file with .png extension in outlook inbox. So can i convert all those images to .gif as shown below? Will it failure in any scenario?

```
if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= item.Attachments.Count; j++)
    {
        string value = item.Attachments[j].PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E");

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            index++;
            string tempFilename = "C:\\TestFileSave\\" + "inlineimg_" + index.ToString() + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(item.Attachments[j].FileName);
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(item.Attachments[j].FileName) == "mso")
            {
                continue;
            }
            item.Attachments[j].SaveAsFile(tempFilename);

            string mimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(tempFilename);
            if (mimeType.Contains("image/"))
            {
                System.Drawing.Image Image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempFilename);
                Image1.Save("C:\\TestFileSave\\" + "inlineimg_" + index.ToString() + ".gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                Image1.Dispose();
                System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilename);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MSO fiel format is not documented. I asked MS dev support about opening its format, but they told me that they have no plans to do that.

Comment: So are they internally used by outlook and not to be used by the user?